# Display JSON Object from console

Tags: json

I have a JSON object returned in my console, and I want to display those data named "offers".

the JSON object is returned like that :

[image]

I tried to display my JSON Object data with :

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

The thing is, it says that "data is not defined"

Does anyone know what happens ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add full path to element of json, for example if your json looks like:

```
var json = {"par":22, "par2":555, "elems":[{"attr1":53, "attr2":99}] };
```

and if you want to get `attr1` value, you should do something like this:

```
console.log(json.elems[0].attr1); // 53
```

so in your case that could be something like:

```
variableName.result.data.offers //variableName is variable that your "consoling"
```

Method `JSON.stringify` doesn't get yout specified value from JSON structure, it's converts JSON object to string.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure to understand what is the variableName ?

Comment: This is that thing that you shows on console. For example if that what you show in picture is given by `console.log(result)`, variableName will be `result`. So you should find in your code, what causes printing object to developer console.

Answer (score 1):

console.dir provides a good representation of object than console.log().U can try with both

```
console.log(result.data.offers[0]);
console.dir(result.data.offers[0]);
```

Comment: it still says that "result is not defined"